# Break line after input without html markup

Tags: html, css, input, label, alignment

I am trying to display a number of inputs and their corresponding labels. They are both inline elements, and I have a working solution with adding a br tag at the end like so

```
<label for="hello"></label>
<input id="hello" type="text" />
<br>
<label for="stackoverflow"></label>
<input id="stackoverflow" />
```

Id like to solve this without extraneous HTML markup, i.e with CSS. What is the easiest way to do this?

I have viewed other questions similar to this, but aligning by row instead of by column.

Comment: Just for argument's sake, this --is-- tabular data.  There was a certain HTML element made to handle that....just sayin'

Answer (score 16):

You can wrap the labels around your inputs and display them as blocks:

```
<style>
  label { display: block; }
</style>

<label>
  Hello: <input name="hello">
</label>
<label>
  StackOverflow: <input name="stackoverflow">
</label>
```

Note that when you do this you don't need to use the `for="name"` attribute.

The other way (if you don't want the labels wrapped around your inputs) is to float the labels to the left:

```
<style>
  label { float: left; clear: left; }
</style>
```

However, I generally prefer a little more markup, something that connects the `label` and the `input` into one logical element, called a *field*:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="hello">Hello</label>
  <input name="hello">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label for="stackoverflow">Stackoverflow</label>
  <input name="stackoverflow">
</div>
```

Because each field is a `div`, it will display as a block automatically, but you can control it for individual fields as well.

Comment: Your "field" div is essentially how I do it too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `display:inline-block` for your `input` and `label` elements. So you can add all block element specific css like `witdh` or `margin-bottom`.

You can also set your `input` and `label` to `display:block` and add `margin-bottom` only to the the input. Or you can reverse it and add a margin-top to your labels ;)

If you want to remove the margin on the last element you can use `input:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}`

```
input, label {display:block;}
input {margin-bottom:18px;}
input:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}

/* Or to be specific you can use the attribut-selector
   which only works on inputs with type="text"
*/
input[type="text"]:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it would still put everything on one line (label-input-label-input) without extra markup.

Comment: You are right. But in this case can set both elements to display:block and add a margin-bottom only to the input elements. I've updated my answer.